# Using Docsets in Cross-site publishing

Tags: 2013, document-set, cross-site-publishing

We have some document sets that we are looking at using in a cross-site publishing set up. The docset and its metadata come through the search just fine, but we aren't sure how to "reassemble" the contents of the docset.

If the children of the set have metadata it too comes through the search, but with no indication (that we see directly) of which docset it belongs to.

​There must be a  property or something that says, "This docset contains these documents." right?

Is there some documentation of all the behind the scenes properties that make a document set work?